# How do I get Ribbons?

Tags: final-fantasy-7

I know that I can morph Master Tonberry in order to get a Ribbon, but he is a very tough guy…

Are there any other ways to get Ribbons?

Comment: For future readers: the Ribbon is an accessory that prevents all status ailments. See http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Ribbon

Comment: See also http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Master_Tonberry_(Final_Fantasy_VII)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Location of the Ribbons are as follows:

- Gaea's Cliff in a hidden passage (Disc 2)
- Temple of the Ancients in room V of the clock room (When accessible)
- By winning 10 Special Battles in the Gold Saucer at the battle square

Alternatively, you can get infinite more by morphing these enemies:
     Master Tonberry (Northern Crater)
     Ho-chu (Special Battle Square)

Also, it might be helpful to note that Yuffies ultimate weapon, The Conformer, does not take the morph damage reduction penalty, meaning she can still do 9999 damage with Morph. This allows Master Tonberries to be easily morphed.
It is also good to know that Master Tonberry can be located in the Nothern Crater Swamp area and has 44444 HP.

All information was taken from [this](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps/197341-final-fantasy-vii/faqs/42714) guide.

Comment: What Most people do against Master Tonberry: 4x Cut with max damage with one char (39996 dmg), then morph with Yuffie (needs to do 4448 damage) .

Comment: I think I'll go with these one...although I don't have Yuffie in my party: I've got the Conformer though, so I'll take her, morph a couple of Tonberry, and let her go stealing something.

Answer (score -1):

You can also morph the Ho-chu in the Battle arena into a ribbon. They're not difficult to beat so you can virtually get one for every character while you build points for the Omnislash and the W-summon materia.